# Let $p > 1$ and $q > 1$. Show that $\frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{y^q}{q} \geq \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}$ for all $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ with $xy = 1$.

Tags: analysis

I'm being asked to show this inequality on the way towards proving Young's inequality. I see in other posts there is usually a given about about the sum of the RHS, but this is the prompt I was given.

Let $p > 1$ and $q > 1$. Show that $\frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{y^q}{q} \geq \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}$  for all $x > 0$ and $y > 0$ with $xy = 1$.

I've tried numerous algebraic tricks and it always seems to be insufficient information. Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{y^q}{q} 
\geq \frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{y^q}{q} 
&=\frac{x^p}{p} + \frac{x^{-q}}{q}\\
&=f(x)\\
\end{array}
$

If $x = y = 1$,
$f(x) = \frac1{p}+\frac1{q}$.

Therefore we can assume that
$x, y \ne 1$.

Choose $x$ so that
$x \gt 1$;
if not,
swap $x$ and $y$.

$f'(x)
=x^{p-1}- x^{-q+1}
=x^{p-1}(1- x^{-q+1-(p-1)})
=x^{p-1}(1- x^{-q-p+2})
=0
$
for
$x=1$.

Since $x > 1$,
and $p+q > 2$,
 then
$x^{-q-p+2}
\lt 1$
so that
$f'(x) > 0$.

Therefore
$f(x)$ is increasing
for $x > 1$
so it is a minimum
at $x = 1$
where
$f(1)
=\frac1{p}+\frac1{q}
$.